# Python logging: disable stack trace

Tags: python, traceback, python-logging

Is there a simple way to disable the logging of an exception stack trace in Python 3, either in a `Handler` or `Formatter`?

I need the stack trace in another `Handler`, so setting `exc_info=False`, in the call to the `Logger` is not an option. Is there a simpler way than just defining my own `Formatter`?

Answer (score 16):

The easiest option to disable *per handler* traceback output is to add a custom [`logging.Filter` subclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Filter) that alters the record object (rather than filter out records).

The filter simply has to set `exc_info` on records to `None`:

```
class TracebackInfoFilter(logging.Filter):
    """Clear or restore the exception on log records"""
    def __init__(self, clear=True):
        self.clear = clear
    def filter(self, record):
        if self.clear:
            record._exc_info_hidden, record.exc_info = record.exc_info, None
            # clear the exception traceback text cache, if created.
            record.exc_text = None
        elif hasattr(record, "_exc_info_hidden"):
            record.exc_info = record._exc_info_hidden
            del record._exc_info_hidden
        return True
```

and [add that filter on your handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.addFilter):

```
# do not display tracebacks in messages handled with this handler,
# by setting the traceback cache to a non-empty string:
handler_with_no_tracebacks.addFilter(TracebackInfoFilter())
```

**However**, handlers do not *copy* log records, and any other handler that is passed the same log record *later on* will also ignore formatting the traceback. So you also need to configure any *other* handlers to restore the information again:

```
for handler in logger.handlers:
    if not any(isinstance(f, TracebackInfoFilter) for f in handler.filters):
        handler.addFilter(TracebackInfoFilter(clear=False))
```

If anyone wanted to disable **all** traceback outputs, everywhere, then perhaps adding a custom filter to all handlers or loggers becomes tedious. In that case another option is to register a custom record factory with the [`logging.setLogRecordFactory()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.setLogRecordFactory); just set the `exc_info` attribute on records to `None`, unconditionally:

```
record_factory = logging.getLogRecordFactory()

def clear_exc_text(*args, **kwargs):
    record = record_factory(*args, **kwargs)
    record.exc_info = None
    return record

logging.setLogRecordFactory(clear_exc_text)
```

Note that the default factory is just the [`logging.LogRecord` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord), but the above function does its best to work with any already-set custom factory.

Of course, you can also create your own `Handler` subclass where the [`Handler.handle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.handle) sets and clears the `exc_info` attribute:

```
class NoTracebackHandler(logging.Handler):
    def handle(self, record):
        info, cache = record.exc_info, record.exc_text
        record.exc_info, record.exc_text = None, None
        try:
            super().handle(record)
        finally:
            record.exc_info = info
            record.exc_text = cache
```

Comment: I have used two handlers, for console and file. I dont want stack trace on console , I used above approach but stack trace is getting printed on both console and file. Below is the code """""""fileHandler = logging.FileHandler("{0}/{1}".format(logPath, fileName))
fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
Logger.addHandler(fileHandler)

consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
consoleHandler.addFilter(SetTracebackCacheFilter(''))
Logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)""""""""

Comment: @ragireddysricharanreddy: ick, I see what is going wrong; an empty string still is seen as an empty cache. I'll rework this answer.

Comment: I resolved it....we need to add record.exc_info = False in filter function

Comment: @ragireddysricharanreddy: I set it to `None`. Take into account that this will affect *other* handlers if they are run later on.

Comment: Nice solution but a word of caution (which is not the fault of @Martijn Pieters). If your handler is behind a QueueHandler you must override the QueueHandler.prepare() function so that the only thing it does is `return record`. Otherwise it is modifying the record so that this solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done even easier than [Digoya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71844292/119527):

```
class NoTracebackFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def formatException(self, ei):
        return ""
    def formatStack(self, stack_info):
        return ""
```

(Tested on Python 3.9)

Comment: This is nice and straightforward, but it means the exception's type and arguments don't get output either, so I've built on it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77581890/1450294

Comment: I cannot get this to work for two different formatters and handlers (the original, and the "no traceback" version).

Answer (score 0):

Late response but it might me useful for somebody else. You don't need to bother with `Handler` nor `Filter`. You just need to inherit your own `Formatter` and skip the part where you format exception. Here is a snippet I use:

```py
class EnhancedFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, fmt=None, datefmt=None, style='%', validate=True, skip_traceback=False):
        self.skip_traceback = skip_traceback
        super(EnhancedFormatter, self).__init__(fmt, datefmt, style, validate)

    def format(self, record) -> str:
        record.message = record.getMessage()
        if self.usesTime():
            record.asctime = self.formatTime(record, self.datefmt)
        s = self.formatMessage(record)
        if not self.skip_traceback: # check here do you need to format traceback
            if record.exc_info:
                if not record.exc_text:
                    record.exc_text = self.formatException(record.exc_info)
            if record.exc_text:
                if s[-1:] != "\n":
                    s = s + "\n"
                s = s + record.exc_text
            if record.stack_info:
                if s[-1:] != "\n":
                    s = s + "\n"
                s = s + self.formatStack(record.stack_info)
        return s
```

Just set `skip_traceback` argument while instantiating the formatter class and later use it to determine do you need to format traceback or not.

Comment: How would you use this function in a real world scenario? I'm new to Python and researching exception handling, and this looks like it would work great. As an example, if I wanted to raise an error when a passed file doesn't exist - how would I use your function? I'd like to hide the stack trace and just output my error.

Comment: @fmotion1, if you want to omit the trace only for very specific exception you created yourself you need to check that record.exc_info is an instance of your specific exception, something like that: `if not isintance(MySpecialException, record.exc_info) and not self.skip_traceback:`

Answer (score 0):

[Johothon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73695412/1450294) is nice and straightforward, but it excludes all exception information, not just the stack. An exception's type and arguments can be useful for devops and end users, so I've modified their code to include it:

```py
class NoTracebackFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def formatException(self, exc_info):
        return '%s: %s' % (exc_info[0].__name__, exc_info[1])
    def formatStack(self, stack_info):
        return ""
```

Then it's just `handler.setFormatter(NoTracebackFormatter())`.

This works nicely for me in Python 3.11.